# Hamel basis and Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a linear space and $X$ has a Hamel basis with uncountable number of  elements. Does there exist a norm on $X$ such that $X$ is a Banach space with respect to this norm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can answer this question when the cardinality $\lambda$ of Hamel basis of $X$ is not less than $\mathfrak{c}$.

For any infinite dimensional Banach space its cardinality and cardinality of its Hamel basis are equal. See theorem 3.5 from [The cardinality of Hamel bases of Banach spaces by Lorenz Halbeisen , Norbert Hungerbühler](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/pdf/hamel.pdf).

Consider Banach space $\ell_\infty(\Lambda)$. Clearly $\operatorname{Card}(\ell_\infty(\lambda))=\lambda\times \operatorname{Card}(\mathbb{C})=\lambda$, so cardinalities of Hamel bases of $\ell_\infty(\lambda)$ and $X$ coincide. Therefore, there is  some linear isomorphism between $X$ and $\ell_\infty(\Lambda)$. This isomorphism induces complete norm on $X$.

Answer (score 1):

The cardinality $\lambda$ of a Hamel basis of an infinite-dimensional Banach space always satisfies $\lambda^\omega =\lambda$. Choose your favourite uncountable cardinal without this property.

Comment: @ Tomasz Kania Kindly provide a reference